# The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required

Tags: core-service, binary

While we are uploading images using Coreservice StreamUploadClient.UploadBinaryContent method we are getting the below error.
 "The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required."
Apprciate your help.

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Are you using the out of the box core service client? Or have you generated one yourself?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status 411 (Length Required) is usually raised when you are doing a POST but haven't specified the size of the body of the request (i.e. the length of the content that you are saving).

Since you didn't post your code, I can't give you a more specific suggestion than: look at the properties of the class you are using to do the request. For instance, if using an `HttpWebRequest` object there is a `ContentLength` property that you should set to the number of bytes of the file you are uploading.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, look at increasing the timeout and maxRequestLength. Here's a sample web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4000000000" maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="9999"/>
                </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, where should we mention these settings if we use app.config for console application

Comment: I hope you can add these setting in the IIS as well and it will take care the internal details for you

Comment: Hi Robert, Still the issue persists,we are using streamUpload_basicHttp and the below configuration 
 <binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" openTimeout="05:00:00" sendTimeout="05:00:00" receiveTimeout="05:00:00" closeTimeout="05:00:00">

          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>

Answer (score 0):

if your not sure how to set up the binding configuration in web/app config file, u can also add the config on ur code directly see the below code.

`BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = 10485760,
                    MaxArrayLength = 10485760
                },
                MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom,
                Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
                }
            };
            EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://domain paths/CoreService2011.svc/streamUpload_basicHttp"); 
StreamUploadClient client = new StreamUploadClient(basicHttpBinding, remoteAddress);`